# does non-encrypted swap ever store encryption keys?

Tags: memory, encryption, swap

I have 2G RAM and 4G swap file. also I have encrypted storage for files. when I boot up my machine there are 100-120M RAM used so plenty of RAM available and swap won't be used (I guess?). If I unlock my storage and later heavily use RAM so I will need my swap file, is it possible that encryption keys will be moved there? I mean this is kind of a silly question, but just to be sure. No hibernation, only sleep; stock kernel without special memory randomizations etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the way that encryption and key storage is done, but you should assume the answer is yes. Stuff are written to the swap space is essentially the data space of user programs. Anything in the linux kernel is going to stay in memory (as you have specified no hibernation), so once information is passed down to the kernel and the user space programs have exited then no keys will be written to swap. However things like FUSE which run in user space can have keys which are written to swap, and if you happened to be zipping or unzipping something when there was a shortage of real memory then keys for that could be written to swap although it would be unlikely.